# Creating threads in method in Console fails in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I am new in Threads.
And wanted to write a simple program with threads in C#.
The goal was when I press any key it must create new thread,
and every thread must write count which increments it's value every time,
when new thread was created. But result was not what expected :).
It first waits for keypress and after keypress it writes only **111111111111111...**. It does not write 2, 3 ,4 and etc. So what is the problem? How can I solve it?
The expected result was like that:
**11112222333311112222333344441111...**
The code is below.

```
class Program
    {
        static Thread t;
        static int count = 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Thread Test";

            t = new Thread(wait);
            t.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread End...");
        }

        static void write(object o)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write(o.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static void wait()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            Thread tt = new Thread(write);
            tt.Start(count);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put one breakpoint in the wait() method, and one in the write(object o) method. Run with the debugger attached, and observe what happens. You should be able to find out the _why_ pretty soon.

Comment: Or put more bluntly: you are missing a loop. Just how many key values do you think your program can get from the user if you only call `ReadKey()` once? (Why people are voting to close due to lack of an MCVE I have no idea; the code example is fine, it's the fact that it's essentially a typographical error that keeps the question from being on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a recursive wait() method is what you want?

```
    static void wait()
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        Thread tt = new Thread(write);
        tt.Start(count);
        count++;

        wait(); //Added
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample :-)

You can try to create more different tasks with different priority.
In the write() method you can printing the name of current task, if you want storage in class more different value you can add property through inheritance

```
class Program
{

    static List<Thread> lst = new List<Thread>();

    //static Thread t;
    static int count = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.Title = "Thread Test";

        createThread();

        foreach (Thread t in lst) t.Start();


        //System.Console.WriteLine("Main Thread End...");
    }



    static void write()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            System.Console.Write(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    static void createThread()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (count<=5)
        {

            Thread tt = new Thread(write);

            if (rnd.Next(0,10)>=5)
            {
                tt.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            }
            else
            {

                tt.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            }



            tt.Name = count.ToString();
            lst.Add(tt);
            count++;
        }



    }

}
```